# Reduce CPU when utilizing GPU to decode RTMP streams to still frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to connect to a RTMP stream (streaming at 30 FPS) and filter the input to 1 FPS and output it as rawvideo. I'm running the current

```
ffmpeg -surfaces 8 -vcodec h264_cuvid -vsync 0 -i rtmp://serveraddress -filter_complex [0]fps=fps=1[s0] -map [s0] -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24
```

The system is running on a T4 Tesla. The application requires ~20 ffmpeg processes to start up, but I have noticed that the CPU usage is pretty high. Is there anyway to optimize this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks like need more option about input area at ffmpeg

added option `-hwacccel cuvid` seems like below

`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -surfaces 8 -vcodec h264_cuvid -vsync 0 -i rtmp://serveraddress -filter_complex [0]fps=fps=1[s0] -map [s0] -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24`

need check about real execute by `h264_cuvid`

therefore, you need trace execute about ffmpeg action by `-loglevel debug`
`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -surfaces 8 -vcodec h264_cuvid -vsync 0 -i rtmp://serveraddress -filter_complex [0]fps=fps=1[s0] -map [s0] -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -loglevel debug`

---

`-f rawvideo` option is execute under cpu

if you need gpu accelerator, check option below

`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -surfaces 8 -vcodec h264_cuvid -vsync 0 -i rtmp://serveraddress -filter_complex [0]fps=fps=1[s0] -map [s0] -c:v h264_nvenc -preset hqll -pix_fmt rgb0`

---

- `h264_nvenc` option reference below

```sh
Encoder h264_nvenc [NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder]:
    General capabilities: delay hardware 
    Threading capabilities: none
    Supported pixel formats: yuv420p nv12 p010le yuv444p p016le yuv444p16le bgr0 rgb0 cuda
h264_nvenc AVOptions:
  -preset            <int>        E..V..... Set the encoding preset (from 0 to 11) (default medium)
     default                      E..V..... 
     slow                         E..V..... hq 2 passes
     medium                       E..V..... hq 1 pass
     fast                         E..V..... hp 1 pass
     hp                           E..V..... 
     hq                           E..V..... 
     bd                           E..V..... 
     ll                           E..V..... low latency
     llhq                         E..V..... low latency hq
     llhp                         E..V..... low latency hp
     lossless                     E..V..... 
     losslesshp                   E..V..... 
  -profile           <int>        E..V..... Set the encoding profile (from 0 to 3) (default main)
     baseline                     E..V..... 
     main                         E..V..... 
     high                         E..V..... 
     high444p                     E..V..... 
  -level             <int>        E..V..... Set the encoding level restriction (from 0 to 51) (default auto)
     auto                         E..V..... 
     1                            E..V..... 
     1.0                          E..V..... 
     1b                           E..V..... 
     1.0b                         E..V..... 
     1.1                          E..V..... 
     1.2                          E..V..... 
     1.3                          E..V..... 
     2                            E..V..... 
     2.0                          E..V..... 
     2.1                          E..V..... 
     2.2                          E..V..... 
     3                            E..V..... 
     3.0                          E..V..... 
     3.1                          E..V..... 
     3.2                          E..V..... 
     4                            E..V..... 
     4.0                          E..V..... 
     4.1                          E..V..... 
     4.2                          E..V..... 
     5                            E..V..... 
     5.0                          E..V..... 
     5.1                          E..V..... 
  -rc                <int>        E..V..... Override the preset rate-control (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
     constqp                      E..V..... Constant QP mode
     vbr                          E..V..... Variable bitrate mode
     cbr                          E..V..... Constant bitrate mode
     vbr_minqp                    E..V..... Variable bitrate mode with MinQP (deprecated)
     ll_2pass_quality              E..V..... Multi-pass optimized for image quality (deprecated)
     ll_2pass_size                E..V..... Multi-pass optimized for constant frame size (deprecated)
     vbr_2pass                    E..V..... Multi-pass variable bitrate mode (deprecated)
     cbr_ld_hq                    E..V..... Constant bitrate low delay high quality mode
     cbr_hq                       E..V..... Constant bitrate high quality mode
     vbr_hq                       E..V..... Variable bitrate high quality mode
  -rc-lookahead      <int>        E..V..... Number of frames to look ahead for rate-control (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
  -surfaces          <int>        E..V..... Number of concurrent surfaces (from 0 to 64) (default 0)
  -cbr               <boolean>    E..V..... Use cbr encoding mode (default false)
  -2pass             <boolean>    E..V..... Use 2pass encoding mode (default auto)
  -gpu               <int>        E..V..... Selects which NVENC capable GPU to use. First GPU is 0, second is 1, and so on. (from -2 to INT_MAX) (default any)
     any                          E..V..... Pick the first device available
     list                         E..V..... List the available devices
  -delay             <int>        E..V..... Delay frame output by the given amount of frames (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default INT_MAX)
  -no-scenecut       <boolean>    E..V..... When lookahead is enabled, set this to 1 to disable adaptive I-frame insertion at scene cuts (default false)
  -forced-idr        <boolean>    E..V..... If forcing keyframes, force them as IDR frames. (default false)
  -b_adapt           <boolean>    E..V..... When lookahead is enabled, set this to 0 to disable adaptive B-frame decision (default true)
  -spatial-aq        <boolean>    E..V..... set to 1 to enable Spatial AQ (default false)
  -temporal-aq       <boolean>    E..V..... set to 1 to enable Temporal AQ (default false)
  -zerolatency       <boolean>    E..V..... Set 1 to indicate zero latency operation (no reordering delay) (default false)
  -nonref_p          <boolean>    E..V..... Set this to 1 to enable automatic insertion of non-reference P-frames (default false)
  -strict_gop        <boolean>    E..V..... Set 1 to minimize GOP-to-GOP rate fluctuations (default false)
  -aq-strength       <int>        E..V..... When Spatial AQ is enabled, this field is used to specify AQ strength. AQ strength scale is from 1 (low) - 15 (aggressive) (from 1 to 15) (default 8)
  -cq                <float>      E..V..... Set target quality level (0 to 51, 0 means automatic) for constant quality mode in VBR rate control (from 0 to 51) (default 0)
  -aud               <boolean>    E..V..... Use access unit delimiters (default false)
  -bluray-compat     <boolean>    E..V..... Bluray compatibility workarounds (default false)
  -init_qpP          <int>        E..V..... Initial QP value for P frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -init_qpB          <int>        E..V..... Initial QP value for B frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -init_qpI          <int>        E..V..... Initial QP value for I frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -qp                <int>        E..V..... Constant quantization parameter rate control method (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -weighted_pred     <int>        E..V..... Set 1 to enable weighted prediction (from 0 to 1) (default 0)
  -coder             <int>        E..V..... Coder type (from -1 to 2) (default default)
     default                      E..V..... 
     auto                         E..V..... 
     cabac                        E..V..... 
     cavlc                        E..V..... 
     ac                           E..V..... 
     vlc                          E..V..... 
  -b_ref_mode        <int>        E..V..... Use B frames as references (from 0 to 2) (default disabled)
     disabled                     E..V..... B frames will not be used for reference
     each                         E..V..... Each B frame will be used for reference
     middle                       E..V..... Only (number of B frames)/2 will be used for reference
  -a53cc             <boolean>    E..V..... Use A53 Closed Captions (if available) (default true)
```

---

if you need more gpu accelerator information about bitrate, quality, pixel format.. whatever
check this [Link](https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg)

### !Important

if you optimizing work about gpu accelerator, check this [GPU Matrix Table](https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-decode-gpu-support-matrix) and [FFmpeg GPU Transcoding Guide](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide/)

it's can be reduce mistakes.

if you need more information, feed me

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help! I tried `ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -surfaces 8 -vcodec h264_cuvid -vsync 0 -i rtmp://serveraddress -filter_complex [0]fps=fps=1[s0] -map [s0] -c:v h264_nvenc -preset hqll -pix_fmt rgb0`, But I'm getting the error `Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_fps_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'`. I think that it is complaining about the pixel conversion. I read that only `yuv420p` is supported in hardware.

Comment: can you try adding this command ? - `[0:v]hwdownload,format=nv12,format=rgb0` full command example - `ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -surfaces 8 -vcodec h264_cuvid -vsync 0 -i rtmp://serveraddress -filter_complex "[0:v]hwdownload,format=nv12,format=rgb0,fps=fps=1[s0]" -map [s0] -c:v h264_nvenc -preset hqll -pix_fmt rgb0` . this command mean is "download frames to CPU (on RAM) from GPU Ram (on VRAM) for auto_scaler processing (auto_scaler processing is cpu work)

Comment: and look up OS monitoring as htop, nmon,,, whatever